# Changing Popup Row Height after Font Size

Tags: delphi, fonts, delphi-5, popupmenu

I need my Visually impaired User to be able select a font size and mostly I have it handled OK, but Popup Menu is not working well as the Row height is not changed with Font Size.

Using this...

```
puMenuMain.OwnerDraw:=True;
Screen.MenuFont.Size:=18;  // Actually selected from list by User or Helper
```

Works well for the Font Size, but the Row height is not changed. In other Components such as TDBGrid, a Font.Size change also changes the Row Height.

How can I get the Popup Menus to adjust the Row Height for the selected Font.Size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Menus.TPopupMenu.OwnerDraw) for `OwnerDraw` property for `TPopupMenu` states:

> When OwnerDraw is true, menu items receive an OnMeasureItem and an
>   OnDrawItem event when they need to be rendered on screen.

So assign a handler for `OnMeasureItem` of the items of the popup menu either at design time, or at run time:

```
puMenuMain.OwnerDraw:=True;
Screen.MenuFont.Size:=18; 
for i := 0 to puMain.Items.Count - 1 do
  puMain.Items[i].OnMeasureItem := PopupMeasureItem;
```

where `PopupMeasureItem` can be as simple as

```
procedure TMyForm.PopupMeasureItem(Sender: TObject; ACanvas: TCanvas;
  var Width,   Height: Integer); 
begin
  Height := ACanvas.TextHeight('.') + 2;
end;
```

or you can determine the necessary height as the user selects from the list to save calling `TextHeight` each time an item is to be drawn.

Answer (score 2):

1. Add an empty `ImageList` component to your form.
2. Set its `Height` property to the value you need.
3. Associate `Images` property of your `PopupMenu` with this `ImageList`.
4. Profit! :)